# Change Windows service name in task manager\resource monitor

Tags: c#, windows-services

Our Windows services are designed in a way such that there is a base class that does all the general service specific stuff. Depending on an argument passed into it, it loads a particular external dll which contains all of that modules specific code.

The problem with this is that the name of the program as shown in task manager and resource monitor is the name of the base service app. As such all of the services show up as the same name in these programs and it's awkward to track which is which.

I've found out that the name comes from the `.exe` name of the app but duplicating the executable is not something I want to do.

In task manager you frequently see Service Host that can be expanded to show the service that is running and looks to be a potential solution. However, this only appears to be with Windows services.

Is there a way to change the name of the service as it shows in these two programs?

Comment: Service Host is special, i don't think you can do that yourself.

Comment: Is my understanding of your scenario correct? Basically: "You have a custom service host process that dynamically determines what service to load, without reference to the Windows service configuration store via a single 'installed' Windows Service"

Comment: @Rob One service class which loads in a different module depending on arguments passed to it. So multiple installed Windows Services

Comment: You actually have multiple services installed, i.e. if you look in `services.msc` each of the services is listed discretely, one per argument passed in / DLL loaded ?

Comment: @Rob Yes say I have 4 modules, I will have 4 different services installed. Services.msc shows each service name as declared by `ServiceBase.ServiceName` but resource monitor shows the service as the executable name.

Comment: If the services are being installed via a `ServiceInstaller` class, it has a `DisplayName` property that can be customized. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Display name only updates the service name in `services.msc`, if you view the service in ResourceMonitor and some versions of TaskManager it uses the executable name. I'm wondering if there's a way to use the display name in these too, if not use a service host, or similar, and have it show the service name that way.

Comment: I *think* you may be stuck then :( Even svchost.exe turns up in some places in-disambiguated :/ Unless the executable is monstrously huge, perhaps just bite the bullet and duplicate it? Far from elegant, but if it gives you what you're after for relatively little time cost,.... :)

Comment: @Rob Yeah don't think it'd work for us, my boss doesn't want to do it for a start. But we also embed the dll's into the main exe for some other reasons so it does become quite big.